# IPhone6/6plus landscape status bar hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6

This is an extension of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036744/display-status-bar-on-landscape-orientation-for-ios-8) regarding displaying status bar for iOS8. Unfortunately, I needed to enable my apps to display the status bar on landscape orientation regardless of fixed or rotated.

With my answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036744/display-status-bar-on-landscape-orientation-for-ios-8), the behaviour on the iPhone6 Simulator (not sure on actual device for now) the status bar doesn't get displayed. Yet when the application is resumed from other application or home screen it gets displayed. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

No that is not normal, however you should not be greatly concerned if you are running a beta version of XCode 6. If you are running the final version however, I would recommend creating a new project after ensuring that XCode is updated and test if the simulator is giving the same results. Try simulators for other devices as well. If none of that works, it is something related to the code. Keep in mind that the simulator does not necessarily emulate an actual device identically, I had an orientation bug in one of my apps that did not occur on the final device recently.

Comment: Currently I'm developing the application using XCode6 GM. I've tried your solution to creating a new project and implementing the answers on the other thread, it gets displayed. Unfortunately, this will cost me great amount of time. Is there an easier way to get it working wherein the project was first developed using as early as XCode4?